# Swift 5 - Sharing location using vCardURL

Tags: swift, coordinates, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to share an address through UIActivityViewController.

This is how I get the URL:

```
func vCardURL(from coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, with name: String?) -> URL {
    let vCardFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("vCard.loc.vcf")
    let vCardString = [
        "BEGIN:VCARD",
        "VERSION:4.0",
        "FN:\(name ?? "Shared Location")",
        "item1.URL;type=pref:http://maps.apple.com/?ll=\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)",
        "item1.X-ABLabel:map url",
        "END:VCARD"
        ].joined(separator: "\n")
    do {
        try vCardString.write(toFile: vCardFileURL.path, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error, \(error.localizedDescription), saving vCard: \(vCardString) to file path: \(vCardFileURL.path).")
    }
        return vCardFileURL
}

func didTapShareButton() {        
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.520007, longitude: 13.404954)
    let url = self.vCardURL(from: coordinate, with: "Berlin")
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)

    //Here it opens the UIActivityViewController
    present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

URL Output:

```
file:///Users/edoardodecal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E1A8A47C-ABF7-4048-ACB1-0AC91E7E0B5B/data/Containers/Data/Application/F79E6A32-B2E7-4137-A75B-AFDE3294A1C2/tmp/vCard.loc.vcf
```

This is the result:

[image]

What I expect:
[image]

Any hints? Thanks

Comment: please check this out -> https://josephduffy.co.uk/posts/ios-share-sheets-the-proper-way-locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget all this stuff. The only thing you need is to share the Apple Maps URL with the coordinates... That's it! Tested on iOS 14 with UIKit and SwiftUI.

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://maps.apple.com?ll=\(latitude),\(longitude)") {
  let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
}
```

And then show the View Controller...